# AWS Java Getting Started InvalidParameterCombination

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting a ''InvalidParameterCombination" error (400) and am very new to EC2. I am unabe to determine the primary issue that is throwing this error. What am I missing? The code dies at the RequestResult. I couldn't find what specific parameters are required so this may be an issue.

```
public class InlineGettingStartedCodeSampleApp {


public static void main(String[] args) {
AWSCredentials credentials = null;
try {
    credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("Assignment3").getCredentials();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new AmazonClientException(
            "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file and is in valid format.", e);
}
AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
    .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_2)
    .build();

RequestSpotInstancesRequest requestRequest = new RequestSpotInstancesRequest();

// Request 1 x t1.micro instance with a bid price of $0.03.
requestRequest.setSpotPrice("0.03");
requestRequest.setInstanceCount(Integer.valueOf(1));

LaunchSpecification launchSpecification = new LaunchSpecification();
launchSpecification.setImageId("ami-fd9cecc7");
launchSpecification.setInstanceType("t1.micro");

System.out.println("set image");
// Add the security group to the request.
ArrayList<String> securityGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
securityGroups.add("GettingStartedGroup");
launchSpecification.setSecurityGroups(securityGroups);

// Add the launch specifications to the request.
requestRequest.setLaunchSpecification(launchSpecification);

// Call the RequestSpotInstance API.
System.out.println("Calling API");
RequestSpotInstancesResult requestResult = ec2.requestSpotInstances(requestRequest); // Dies here
System.out.println("API called");
```

Comment: Can you post more details from your exception? If you set up a try/catch block around `ec2.requestSpotInstances` request and catch the `InvalidParameterCombinationException`, you can print the results of `getErrorMessage` for a more human-readable description of what went wrong.

Comment: your request seems to be missing required information for requesting spot instances. Look at documentation at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#requestSpotInstances-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.RequestSpotInstancesRequest-